# Database flutter Vs native(Android)

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter and skeptical about holding database either in android or flutter.

My app do rely on background listening, So saving the data in android is the right way to sync with server right now.

But I'm confused this might be trouble in future?. By storing data only in android and not in flutter. Will it affect in future?.

If I want to store in flutter, I'm not sure about how to store the data from android to flutter (SQL) in background.

So storing the data in android is the nice way or in the flutter would be good thing?.

Please clear my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Always store data using flutter code it will be saved to ios and android automatically as per platform.

1. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_orm_plugin
2. https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter
3. https://pub.dev/packages/sqfentity

About background

1. Learn isolates
2. https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
3. https://pub.dev/packages/worker_manager